# What does calling setsockopt three times with different options do

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am looking at some code and came across something like this..

```
class ThreadingUDPLLMNRServer(ThreadingMixIn, UDPServer):
    def server_bind(self):
        MADDR = "224.0.0.252"
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 255)
        
        Join = self.socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,socket.inet_aton(MADDR) + settings.Config.IP_aton)
...
```

The function in question is `setsockopt()`. From my understanding if you call a function on something multiple times, it will just update it. But here I don't see why you would do this since nothing is checking after each call. By calling it multiple times is it just basically giving that socket more options and each call is basically adding that info to it?

Comment: How else would you set three different options on a socket?

Answer (score 2):

There are many socket options, some [standardized](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_16) more than others; each call is setting a **different** option on the socket.